# Android Live Wallpaper

Tags: android

I'm making a live wallpaper app and I was just wondering if I can create a background in photoshop and then place animations on top of that. I'm new to this and all the examples I've seen online don't really mention anything about this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It depends on what you are using for creating that live wallpaper. I assume you are using an engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using AndEngine for android. it has an addon specifically made for creating live wallpapers. you can also find some examples of usage in the andEngine examples.

Now a layered structure is pretty common and definitely should and can be used. So stacking photos isn't an issue but you really need to be careful about their sizes because you can quickly run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

- Create the background in photoshop
- Save it as png
- Create a square in opengl
- Texture the square using your background png
- square should fit the screen in order to look like a background
- Then create the animation or whatever in front of the background